# How do you add Ionic 3 Ipad Styles

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

how to add Ionic platform specific styles for Ipad.
I have different styles for tablets and mobile displays.

Thanks

Comment: use media query and an minimum width of an ipad is 720px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways:

Global style file: `app.scss`

> It is used to declare any styles that will be used globally throughout
>   the application

`variables.scss`

> is used to modify the apps shared variables

Here is a great [**article about it**](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/):

This is the [**official doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/theming-your-app/) about it.